# Directed graph: how to symmetrically link all nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

First of all, my apologies for the naive phrasing of the problem I could make: English is not my first language and graph theory is not my specialty, so I may not use the correct vocabulary for the problem I describe.
That being said…

I have 56 nodes. Each node must point to 4 other nodes and be pointed at from 4 other nodes, avoiding if possible reciprocal pointings (i.e. A and B do not point to each other).
I also want each node to be accessible from any other node through this succession of directed links (so, only one graph).

> What is the most "symmetrical" way to link all 56 nodes, so there is no difference if we look at the graph from node A or X? Is it even possible?

I guess that the longer the routes from one node to itself, the better ($A\to B\to C\to A$ is not so good, avoid if possible). My other guess is that, if symmetry is indeed possible, we will have something like "for every node, you can go to 4 nodes on one step, $X$ (16?) other nodes on 2 steps, $Y$ (not 64 obviously) other nodes on 3 steps…" until every node is at a maximal distance of every other. Hoping I'm clear enough…

---

In fact, maybe the background of this could help: I'm creating a tabletop game based on 56 tiles, each defined by a unique code, and having 4 other codes leading to the corresponding other tiles. Think dominos, only that each domino can only lead to 4 other dominos, with no reciprocity.

No tile should stand up from the others, hence the symmetrical aspect of the request. For example, we should avoid having tile A at a maximal distance of 3 of every other tile, while tile B could be 5 links away of tile C.

Thank you for your help, and don't hesitate to ask for details if this isn't clear enough.

---

**EDIT since Parcly Taxel answer :**

A flaw I see in the +1+2+3+4 solution is that from a vertex to the next, you can easily find most of the same related vertices (from vertices 0 to 1 you can go to the same vertices 2, 3 & 4), which could lead to unexpected game behaviours.

I tried +1+5+9+13 for the first vertices and it seems to work better on that point (with a girth of 8, still acceptable). I will check this more thoroughly to confirm though.

Is there a way to quickly compute the girth and "reachabilities" from a given set of steps ?

---

**EDIT since M. Winter comments :**

So, the simplest solution seems to be that of Parcly Taxel :

> - The vertices receive labels 0 to 55.
> - There is a directed edge from vertex aa to vertices a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4, where all indices are modulo 56.

However, we saw in the previous edit that the steps +1+2+3+4 are not really great since it tends to repeat some triplets of vertices. In fact, I found that there must be unique differences between the 4 step increments. For example :

- With +1+3+7+15 I have differences of 2, 4, 8, 6, 12 & 14, so it's perfect : no vertex will lead to the same pair or triplets of vertices.
- With +1+3+7+13 however, we have the same diffferences : 7-1 = 13-7 = 6. Hence, from vertex 0 we can go to (1, 3, 7, 13), and from vertex 6 to (7, 9, 13, 19) : both can lead to 7 & 13.

Another issue is the multiple path of length 2. Considering +1+3+7+13, wee se that there is 3 paths of length 2 from a same vertex to another, as for example : $0 \to 7 \to 14$  ,  $0 \to 1 \to 14$ and $0 \to 13 \to 14$. Here again, if all the differences between the steps are unique, we should not have this kind of behaviour.

**The bonus question is :** what is the best quadruplet of steps wich ensures this "differences uniqueness", while maximizing the girth ? So far I have +1+3+7+15, with a girth of 6 (56 = 15+15+15+7+3+1), but I'm not done searching ;)

Comment: In think to find the smallest circle you have to look for a short way to express $56$ as the sum of your numbers $1,2,3,4$ or $1,5,9,13$ respectively. It needs 14 terms in the first case: $4+4+\cdots+4$. It needs 8 in the latter one: $13+13+13+13+1+1+1+1$. This, of course, is no proof.

Comment: You still got some multiple short paths to the same vertex, e.g. $5+5=9+1$, $13+1=9+5$ and $9+9=13+5$. I think you cannot do much better. What multiple path lengths are acceptable?

Comment: If you consider length three as short too, then there are still $1+3+3=7$ and $7+3+3=13$ ;). But there is no way to avoid this for $56$ vertices, because every vertex is left by four edges and after three vertices with no double path this would give $4^3=64$ vertices, which is too much for your graph. So I think this is close to best possible.

Comment: I didn't think a lot about multiple paths, good point. I'll fiddle a bit with other increments to reduce it, so far I'm quite happy with +1+3+7+15 : girth of 6 (15+15+15+7+3+1, still ok), no double short path of length 2, and **no pair/triplets of same vertex from another one** : with+1+5+9+13 you could go to 1,5,9,13 from vertex 0, and to 5, 9, 13, 17 from vertex 4, having twice the 5, 9, 13 ! To avoid this, I found that there must be unique differences between my 4 step increments. With +1+3+7+15 I have differences of 2, 4, 8, 6, 12 & 14, so it's perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a connected vertex-transitive 8-regular directed graph on 56 vertices with high girth. I will explicitly construct such a graph:

- The vertices receive labels 0 to 55.
- There is a directed edge from vertex $a$ to vertices $a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4$, where all indices are modulo 56.

This is an example of a [circulant graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph). Choosing the smallest steps possible – 1, 2, 3 and 4 vertices forward – ensures that the girth is as high as possible: in our construction it is 14.

From any vertex, four vertices are reachable in one step, seven in two steps and ten in three steps.

Comment: Great (and simple) answer ! Plus, thanks for the edit.